# gmail notifier code python

Tags: python-3.x, arduino

I have just started with Python a few days earlier, and now I am trying to make a Gmail notifier for Arduino using Python. I am getting the following error. I have entered my username and ID properly, I have even tried putting application specified code given by Google, but I'm still getting this error.

```
import serial, sys, feedparser,time
#Settings - Change these to match your account details
USERNAME="XXXX"
PASSWORD="XXXXXXX"
PROTO="https://"
SERVER="mail.google.com"
PATH="/gmail/feed/atom/important"
try:
  ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)
except serial.SerialException:
      print ("no device connected exiting")
      sys.exit()
newmails = int(feedparser.parse(PROTO + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD + "@" + SERVER + PATH)["feed"]["fullcount"])
# Output data to serial port
if newmails > 0:
  ser.write("m")
  print("some mail")
else:
  ser.write("n")
  print("no mail")
#print data to terminal
# Close serial port
ser.close()
```

> ERROR IS FOLLOWING :- C:\Python33>python mailarduino.py Traceback
>   (most recent call last): File "mailarduino.py", line 13, in 
>   newmails = int(feedparser.parse(PROTO + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD +
>   "@" + SE RVER + PATH)["feed"]["fullcount"]) File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\feedparser-5.1-py3.3.egg\feedparser.py",
>   l ine 346, in **getitem** return dict.**getitem**(self, key) KeyError:
>   'fullcount'
>
> C:\Python33>

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are copying is 5 years old.  API's, which are the functions you can call and what they return, can change over time.  I suggest printing out:

```
feedparser.parse(PROTO + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD + "@" + SERVER + PATH)
```

and see what that produces.  Once you see what you have, then you can work out how to extract the info you want.